# Where does filter method in js store new array If I am not assigning any variable to it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

```
<script>
    var arr = ["apple", "mango", "apple",
            "orange", "mango", "mango"];

    function removeDuplicates(arr) {
        return arr.filter((item,
            index) => arr.indexOf(item) === index);
    }

    console.log(removeDuplicates(arr));
</script>
```

Is the filter method returning the whole array or each item one by one?

Here I removed duplicates in Function using filter method. My question is I know filter method creates new array but where does it store that array?

Comment: you mean when you directly `console.log()` a function, without assigning results to a variable instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter method returns a whole new array once it’s completed. Primitive values (as you've got here) are cloned, but the filter method won’t deep-clone. So if you’re filtering an array of objects, for example, you’ll still get a new array, but with references to the same objects from the original array.

As far as where it’s stored, it wouldn’t be accessible unless you assign it to a variable.

```
const yourArray = [
    "apple", "mango", "apple",
    "orange", "mango", "mango"
];

const newArray = removeDuplicates(yourArray);

console.log(newArray);

function removeDuplicates(arr) {
    return arr.filter((item,
        index) => arr.indexOf(item) === index);
}
// console shows ["apple","mango","orange"]
```